# When do I need times series analysis for regression on time series data

Tags: regression, machine-learning, time-series, multiple-regression

My problem is I have one (X) or maybe several (X1,...,Xm) independent variables who are the deterministic measurements over time (X(1),X(2),...X(t)) (e.g. temperature of the system is setting by me and changing over time). And I also have one dependent variable y who is also a time series measurements (e.g. the volume of my system over time). I would like to predict my y value based on my measurement X, like giving me an equation of y=f(X).

How should I decide if I should use the simple regression model (e.g. linear regression y=aX+b), or a time series analysis model. Should I just build the simple regression model first and then check the correlations in residual?

Comment: I think you might be better to split this up and ask one question at a time as otherwise it is in danger of being closed as too broad.

Comment: I have voted to reopen as the OP has edited it down to a single question.